# Chrome crashes some pages; memtest86+ shows errors even after replacing RAM

Tags: google-chrome, memory-error

I recently bought an IBM S51 PC (P4 3.2 GHz / 2 x 512 MB PC3200-400 DDR), with Win7 installed.

Noticed that Chrome aw snap-crashed some webpages, particularly those with Flash it seemed. After exchanging Win with Lubuntu 12.10, Chrome still crashes certain webpages.

Ran memtest86+ which showed RAM errors. These errors persist even though I have replaced RAM!

[image: 1]

What can be the cause?

Comment: I would guess first that replacement RAM is bad, or the memory controller/CPU is bad. Does the RAM pass all tests in another system?

Answer (score 3):

If memtest is showing errors after replacing RAM you have 5 possibilities:

1. Memtest is not compatible with your motherboard (unlikely as your motherboard uses a common chipset and is not brand new)
2. It's not your RAM that is faulty, it's the L1 or L2 cache (try running Memtest with cache off).
3. One or more RAM sockets are faulty.
4. There's something else broken in the memory pipeline.
5. You are incredibly unlucky and the replacement RAM is bad also.

If it's not 1 or 4 you are probably stuck replacing your motherboard and/or CPU.

You might try running Memtest with less RAM if possible, or if there are 4 RAM sockets, putting the RAM in the unused sockets instead.

Comment: Thanks for the thorough reply! Couldn't find anywhere in MemTest to turn cache off - should I do it in BIOS? MemTest reports there are 4 slots, but I can only find 2 on the motherboard, the 2 that are in use.